# Why does slope == 1 in regression mean there is no correlation?

Tags: regression, anova

Looking at the picture below we can see that there is a difference in the response based on the predictor. Furthermore, the order of the predictor values were arbitrarily chosen. The slope in this case is 0, but if we rearranged the predictor values from {1,2,3} to {2,1,3} then there would be a positive correlation. Is the only workaround to this anova?
[image]

Comment: Please check the title of your question. Further, does ordering the x-axis make sense? What is that variable? – *Reviewer*

Comment: i said the predictor values were chosen arbitrarily....

Comment: if `dat3$type` is categorical, you need to code it correctly. In `R` this variable should be a `factor`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to not label things arbitrarily and then pretend (in the code) that the labels have meaning.

ANOVA is equivalent to regression. As @Taylor pointed out, in R, this would mean making x a factor.  It would also mean not taking the correlation, as it is a meaningless number. And the graph you made is not appropriate because the presence of intermediate numbers on the x-axis implies that x is continuous (or, at a bare minimum, ordered with some sort of possible meaningful intermediate points) and it is not.  Personally, I generally try to avoid using numbers for non-ordered categorical variables as it helps making the sorts of errors you have made here. Give X labels that make sense in the context of the particular problem.

As to your title question, the answer is "it doesn't.".